# checking all the available Countries for my App

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console, google-console-developer

I have developed an app and I am not sure, if a specific app is visible for a specific country in google play. I have specified a specific country, but it looks like, that that country can't see the app.

To check this, I use a common VPN Client that connects to a spcific host in a country and call google play to see if the app is visible.

But a negativ test doesn't work for me:
I made the app unavailable for kenya. When checking the Google Play, I can see the app.

So my question. How that check, if or not an app is available for specific country, if we do not trust the google play console regarding country distribution ?

Comment: For a specific country you can add a `gl=` country code parameter to the PlayStore `URL` of the app. For example,  `https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.facebook.lite?gl=cn` will show if the app is available in China.